# Webview in android 4.1.2 flicking in black colour on scaling

Tags: android, view, webview, scroll, scaling

I have an issue in Scaling a WebView (say w),if I set the Cache mode as 
`"w.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE)"` and view layer type as ,

```
" w.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);" ,
```

webview is getting invisible on scaling the view above the screen dimensions.But Before using the above lines  while scrolling  and scaling, the webview's background were flickering with black color .Please help me to find a solution.Thank you all.

Comment: remove this lines and disable hardware acceleration for the activity in manifest `android:hardwareAccelerated=false`

Comment: I'll put it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this lines and disable hardware acceleration for the activity in manifest `android:hardwareAccelerated=false`.